# Can the Mathematica calculate the curve integral of the second type？

Tags: numerical-integration, computational-geometry, finite-element-method

Mathematica can calculate the integral over the region. Now I want to use this function to evaluate the second kind curve integral, for example I want to evaluate the integral $\oint P\,\mathrm{d}x+Q\,\mathrm{d}y$ over the boundary of a rectangle mesh region.

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`;
domain = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}];(*a square *)
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[domain];(*region of the boundary*)
P[x_, y_] := x;
Q[x_, y_] := y;
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: No need to do that, just apply the Green's Theorem...

Answer (score 5):

If you still want avoid using Green's Theorem, you must parametrise the boundary. The function `ToBoundaryMesh` gives a collections of points defining your boundary. So you must integrate your boundary along the points connected. In the case of a square, parametrising the boundary is easy:

```
ParametricPlot[{{t, 0}, {1, t}, {1 - t, 1}, {0, 1 - t}}, {t, 0, 1}, 
PlotRange -> {{-0.25, 1.25}, {-0.25, 1.25}}, 
AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.05}], 
AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16, Black, Bold] & /@ {"x", "y"})] /. 
Line[p___] :> {Arrowheads[{0.05}], Arrow[p]}
```

[image]

where the integration must be counterclockwise.

Then, your second order integral with $P(x,y)$, and $Q(x,y)$ with the square parametrised is:

```
Total@((Integrate[#[[1]], {x, 0, 1}] + Integrate[#[[2]], {y, 0, 1}]) & /@ 
Transpose@{{x, 0, -x, 0}, {0, y, 0, -y}})

(* 0 *)
```

which is in agreement with the application of the Green's Theorem:

$\iint_D\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)dxdy=\oint_CPdx+Qdy=0$

where $D$ is the region enclosed by $C$.

I think that for more complicated boundaries, an auxiliary function must be done to parametrize all the segments comprising the boundary given by the coordinates of the points provided by `ToBoundaryMesh`.

Hope this helps.